MongoDB C driver asks to connect a smart card reader when trying to ping atlas database?
When trying to ping MongoDB database though the C driver api, it asks to connect Smart Card Reader?
The auth method used is SCRAM. I copied the connection string from MongoDB site and changed username + password to match the account i have created for managing databases on atlas.
NOTE: Trying to connect to MongoDB database through MongoDB Shell worked fine.
Here's the image of the Smart Card Reader popup
I can't figure out why it tries to use Smart Card Reader as auth method when using C driver? Can somebody more knowledgeable on the topic help out?
Here's the code that causes the "Connect Smart Card Reader" popup to appear
    command = BCON_NEW("ping", BCON_INT32(1));
    ok = mongoc_database_command_simple(
        database, command, NULL, &reply, &error
    );

EDIT:
So if anyone else has similar problem reinstalling Windows fixed the problem and now it pings database just fine.
